# Xcode - how to get rid of line in tab bar graphic

Tags: ios, uitabbar

At the top of my tab bar there is a faint, black line that won't go away. It is not in the original image. I have tried Clip To Bounds, changing the image tint and the background color.

[image]

Comment: Try removing the shadow image, the background image and setting the 'clipToBounds' property to true.
' tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

tabBarController?.tabBar.clipToBounds = true'

Comment: UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true